# Initialize array in constructor without using default constructor or assignment

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, initialization, default

Consider:

```
struct A {

 A (int);

 A (const A &);
};

struct B {

 A foo [2];

 B (const A & x, const A & y)
 : foo {x, y} /* HERE IS THE PROBLEM */
 {}
};
```

I was expecting this to work since I'm using C++0x support in GCC4.3, which allegedly supports initialiser lists. No joy.

I have a class A which has no default constructor. This is not negotiable. Assignment post-default is not an option.

I am trying to create B which uses A. B::foo may not be std::vector.

How can I initialise `B::foo` in `B(...)`, constructing its elements exactly once?

At the moment, I am condidering replacing B with

```
struct B {

A foo_a;

B foo_b;

A * foo () {
assert ((&foo_b) - *&foo_a) == 1);
return &foo_a;
}

B (const A & x, const A & y) : foo_a(x), foo_b(y) {}
};
```

Or even using `char foo [2*sizeof(A)]` with placement new -- YUK!

Surely there's a proper way to do this?

Comment: Just letting you know that I formatted your code blocks a bit more nicely using the "0101" button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there really is no proper, clean way to do this.  Consider it something of a language limitation that results from an awkward mixing of C++ constructors and C style arrays. The C++11 standard addresses this issue, but until then you'll have to settle for a workaround.

Since `A` has no default constructor, one possible work-around is to have an array of `A*` pointers, and then loop over the array and initialize each one with `new`.  (Obviously, don't forget to `delete` each item in the array in B's destructor, or just use smart pointers.)

Comment: Did you read that spraff wrote _"I'm using C++0x support in GCC4.3, which allegedly supports initialiser lists"_?

Comment: I'm pretty sure GCC 4.3's C++0x extension doesn't support initializer lists.  See http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Answer (score 5):

You can use `boost::array`. It has a plain native array inside, so it still has the same memory layout like in your example.

```
struct B {
 boost::array<A, 2> foo;

 B (const A & x, const A & y)
 : foo(createFoo(x, y))
 {}

private:
 static boost::array<A, 2> createFoo(const A & x, const A & y) {
   boost::array<A, 2> a = {{ x, y }};
   return a;
 }
};
```

If you don't have boost you can create your own `array` class or use `std::tr1` if your compiler has it

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct array {
  T data[N];
};
```

That's all you need, but you can add the usual `begin`, `end`, `size` functions and so on to make it more comfortable to use.

Comment: +1  Nice solution.  Although it will invoke A's copy constructor N times, unless the compiler has R-value constructor support.

Comment: @Charles thanks. Though every copy involved except the unavoidable copies of `x` and `y` into `a` are eligible to be optimized: (1) copy of local `a` into the return value, and (2) copy of the return value temporary into `foo`.

Comment: Well, if spraff has a compiler supporting C++0x, shouldn't that also come with `std::array`?

Answer (score 2):

It should work in C++0x, but g++ 4.5.0 complains with "bad array initializer". If you replace `A foo[2]` with `std::vector<A> foo`, it compiles.

Comment: Yes, that was the original intention. Any idea why this fails?

Comment: @spraff taking my comment back. Seems it only works for non-class element types even on GCC4.6 :(

Comment: @spraff: Sounds like a g++ bug to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is similar to this previous question: [C++: constructor initializer for arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409819/c-constructor-initializer-for-arrays)

Your main suggestion (make two members `foo_a` and `foo_b`) is probably the best way of doing things, provided that you'll need only two elements. <strike>There's no way of initializing array elements with anything but the type's default constructor in an initializer list, as you're trying to do in your example.</strike> Edit: Sorry, I didn't see that you were using C++0x. In C++0x you should be able to initialize as you wanted to do, provided that A is copyable or movable. I don't know about GCC 4.3's support for this, though.

Be careful using `char` arrays and placement new - `char` arrays aren't necessarily aligned properly to construct an `A`, and doing this can result in undefined behavior.

Some other suggestions:

- Store an array of pointers to A, or better, an array of smart pointers like `auto_ptr` or `boost::scoped_ptr`, and create the A objects on the heap using `new A(args...)`.
- Store an array of another type, like `boost::optional<A>`, which handles the default construction and the alignment problem for you, but still essentially stores the A objects inside the B object proper.