# Constructing array

Tags: c++, class, constructor, new-operator

How to call specific class constructor within operator `new[]`?

```
#include <iostream>

class foo
{
  public:
    foo(){std::cout << "\nfoo::foo()\n";}
    foo(int param){std::cout << "\nfoo::foo(int)\n";}
};

int main()
{
  foo* my_array = new foo[45];
  return 0;
}
```

`foo* my_array = new foo[45];` would call `foo()` constructor. How to call `foo(int)` constructor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initialize array in constructor without using default constructor or assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798276/initialize-array-in-constructor-without-using-default-constructor-or-assignment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do this for raw arrays. You can achieve similar result with std::vectors' 
`explicit vector (size_type n, const value_type& val = value_type(),
                 const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());`:

```
std::vector<foo> my_vector(45, 10);
```

will create vector with 45 `foo` objects, each created via `foo(10)` constructor call.

Comment: You can shorten that to `std::vector v(45, 10);`

Comment: Aren't you missing the template parameter <foo>? It's also worth noting, that the constructor gets called only once. The other elements will by copies, so an object that manages ressources has to have a proper copy constructor.

Comment: There *is* a way to do this for arrays, it is just a bit tedious for long arrays.