# How do I prototype/populating an array inside a class?(C++)

Tags: c++, class

I want to fill an array that's a member of a class with data. Do I have to create a function that populates it, or is there a way that I can just enter the values directly?

```
class example
{
private:
    struct exm {
        int everything[3];
    };

public:
    exm demo;

    void output();
    void populate();
};
```

If not would this work?

```
void example::populate() {
    demo.everything[0] = 1;
    demo.everything[2] = 1;
    //and so on... (could probably use a for loop)
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: constructor initializer for arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409819/c-constructor-initializer-for-arrays)

Comment: `int everything[3] = {1, 1, 1};`

Comment: @BrandonHaston: Close, but not quite. That question refers to initializing arrays of arbitrary objects. While we can't do this (easily?) for arbitrary objects, we *can* for primitive types like `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since demo is a public member you can access it directly or you can create a member function to set values.

```
#include <iostream>

class example
{
  private:
     struct exm {
        int everything[3];
     };

  public:
    exm demo;
    void output();
    void populate(){
      demo.everything[2] = 1;
    }
};

int main() 
{

  example Test;

  Test.demo.everything[0] = 5;
  Test.populate();

  std::cout<< Test.demo.everything[0]; //outputs 5
  std::cout<< Test.demo.everything[2]; //outputs 1

  return 0;
}
```

`