# Initialize dynamic array objects with the object's copy constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, copy-constructor

I'm currently learning C++ and I'm messing around with constructors/operators.

I have an array:

```
int x(1);
int a[] = { int(x), int(x), int(x) };
```

How can I construct the same array dynamically using the object's copy constructor? I also don't wanna use the = operator.

So something like:

```
int* b;
for (int i = 0; i < DESIRED_ARRAY_SIZE; i += 1)
{
    b[i](int(x));
}
```

Of course the above doesn't work. This is strictly for learning purposes, so I'm wondering if this is possible. I'm also wondering if there's a special case for primitives vs classes, as I'm  currently testing with `int` atm.

Comment: Neither `int` nor `int[]` have a copy constructor. What are you really asking?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409819/c-constructor-initializer-for-arrays . (*)

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> How can I construct the same array dynamically using the object's copy constructor?

Assuming you have a different type than `int` that has a copy constructor, you can use:

```
X x(1);
X arr[] = {x, x, x, x};
```

You said:

> I also don't wanna use the = operator.

If you have the option of using `std::vector`, you can use:

```
std::vector<X> arr(10, x);
```

If using `std::vector` is not an option for some reason, you can use:

```
// Create an array objects. The object will be created using
// the default constructor.
X* arr = new X[DESIRED_ARRAY_SIZE]; 
for (int i = 0; i < DESIRED_ARRAY_SIZE; i += 1)
{
    arr[i] = x; // This will use the copy assignment operator,
                // not the copy constructor.
}
```

Comment: I coded the above snippet that way to explicitly denote that I want to use the copy constructor for each of the array's elements. And I'd like to know if this is possible without using vectors :).

Answer (score 0):

In C++ dynamic arrays are called `vector` and (since C++11) you can write:

```
vector<int> a = { x, x, x };
```

The casts are redundant, `int(x)` is the same as `x`, because `x` is an int already. (That doesn't specify a copy).

Initializer lists copy by value.

In your second example the code is:

```
vector<int> b(DESIRED_ARRAY_SIZE, x);
```

Comment: Can this be done without vectors? I completely forgot to mention that in my problem :(. Oh and yes I'm aware that my code was redundant. See my comment on the other answer.

Comment: "vector" is how you construct arrays using dynamically-allocated memory  in C++ ; that's like asking if you can screw in a screw without using a screwdriver. You could use a hammer but results are not so good...

Answer (score 0):

The `=` sign gets used in two contexts:

1. Initialization - [Copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), [Copy-list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) or [aggregate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) initialization
2. Assignment

When you write something like `int a[] = {1,2,3}`, it is aggregate initialization. If you want to construct an array dynamically, you would use `new[]` to dynamically allocate your array and then go on to copy assign the elements of this array. You do it like this:

```
int* b = new int[DESIRED_ARRAY_SIZE];
for (int i = 0; i < DESIRED_ARRAY_SIZE; i += 1)
{
    b[i] = x;
}
```

There is a difference between using fundamental types like `int` and a class type, say `T`. In the above snippet, you can replace `int` by `T`(and have `x` have type `T`) and it will work if `T` is default constructible and has a copy constructor. If not, there are ways to specify how the objects of type `T` in `b` should be constructed. You can find information in the section titled "Construction" [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new).
Note that there are much better ways to do this in modern C++, but that wasn't what your question was about.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have pointed out, best choice would be to use `std::vector`, else you can use `new` and `delete` althought its not recommended since it's easy to make mistakes. Always remember to `delete[]` when you've created an array using `new` and `delete` if you've just used `new` without making it an array. Consider looking at the other answers here about `std::vector` for dealing with dynamic allocations. If none of the answers are what you're looking for, then perhaps you need to rephrase your question.

```
    int* p_array = new int[3]; // '3' would be the array length
    for (int i{0}; i != 3; ++i)// I'm not naming the arr length in this example.
        p_array[i] = i;  

    delete[] p_array;
```